# Invoke Remote Batch File

Tags: powershell, invoke-command

I am struggling to invoke a batch file stored on a remote server

```
$out = "c:\temp\test.txt"
$sessions = New-PSSession -ComputerName "COMPUTER01"
$cmd = 'C:\Program Files\tool\bin\sc.bat'
$arg1 = "list files >> $out"
Invoke-Command -Session $sessions -ScriptBlock {
    param([string]$arg1)
      & $cmd $arg1
} -ArgumentList ($arg1)
Exit-PSSession
```

What am I missing?

Thanks!

--- UPDATE ----
solution:

```
$out = "c:\temp\test.txt"
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName "COMPUTER01"
$cmd = "C:\Program Files\tool\bin\sc.bat"
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
    param($cmd,$out)
    Invoke-Expression "&'$cmd' list files >> $out"
} -ArgumentList ($cmd,$out)
Remove-PSSession $session
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using Invoke-Expression inside the scriptblock? Like:

`Invoke-Expression "& $cmd $arg1"`

And also you can directly use the `-ComputerName` parameter of `Invoke-Command` instead of using a session.

Comment: Thanks Rohin. I've tried using the Invoke-Expression and it's giving me  `The term 'list' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was 
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.`

Comment: For Troubleshooting purposes, see if this works. `Invoke-Command -ComputerName Computer01 -ScriptBlock {Invoke-Expression '&"C:\Program Files\tool\bin\sc.bat" List Files >> c:\temp\test.txt'}`

Comment: I suppose then all you have to do is reproduce that with substituting variables. I cant test this right now. Maybe try using double quotes around the variables when enclosing the whole command in single quotes.

Comment: Thanks again @rohin-sidharth. I've updated my post with your input.